# Logback does not log ConstraintViolationException in Spring Boot's @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, logback

I am doing some validation on a query parameter in my Spring Boot web service. In this case it is a parameter that does not match the regex `[0-9]{3}`. So in the service method, there is a validation:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{3}") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "AngivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode", required = false) String angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode
```

(`angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode` is just the name of the query parameter)

I am working on a log manager that basically just prints log messages using logback and slf4j.

I have a `writeInternalError(exception)` in my log manager class which nicely logs an exception when told to:

```
public void writeInternalError(Exception exception) {
    logger.error(exception.getClass().getName(), kv("LogType", exception), kv("LogMessage", exception));
}
```

except for when the `ConstraintViolationException` is caught by the `@ExceptionHandler` in my `@ControllerAdvice`. No errors are shown, and a Spring log is outputted instead of my expected custom log. When I debug, the `logger.error()` seems to be executed and no errors are shown.

I have made a quick fix method where I manually extract the information of the exception, but I want to use the same logging method for all exceptions:

```
public void writeTracelog(Exception exception) {
    logger.error(exception.getClass().getName(), kv("LogType", "exception"), kv("ErrorMessage", exception.getMessage()), kv("StackTrace", exception.getStackTrace()));
}
```

The expected and unexpected logs I get are:

```
// The Spring log message shown instead of my custom error message:
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-06-10T12:13:40.730+02:00",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "Resolved [javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: call29f0dab4A3094a30A1cdE29c01f28af8.angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode: must match \"[0-9]{3}\"]",
    "logger_name": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver",
    "thread_name": "http-nio-8082-exec-1",
    "level": "WARN",
    "level_value": 30000
}

// How the log is supposed to look like
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-06-10T14:35:18.257+02:00",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
    "logger_name": "ClsLogManager",
    "thread_name": "http-nio-8082-exec-1",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "level_value": 40000,
    "LogType": "exception",
    "LogMessage": {
        "cause": null,
        "stackTrace": [...],
        "constraintViolations": null,
        "message": "call29f0dab4A3094a30A1cdE29c01f28af8.angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode: must match \"[0-9]",
        "suppressed": [],
        "localizedMessage": "call29f0dab4A3094a30A1cdE29c01f28af8.angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode: must match \"[0-9]"
    }
}
```

When I call `writeInternalError()` with any other exception, the log is nicely output. I have tried different ways of logging to see what works and what does not as you can see in the handler in the `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        // Get the invalid parameter from the ConstraintViolationException

        if (invalidParameter.equalsIgnoreCase("angivelseFrekvensForholdUnderkontoArtKode")) {
            errorMessage = setErrorMessage(request, "422.9", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(), invalidValue);
            clsLogManager.writeTracelog(ex); // Outputs customized unwanted log
            clsLogManager.writeInternalError(new ConstraintViolationException(null)); // Outputs exception in the format I want
            clsLogManager.writeInternalError(ex); // Outputs nothing
            responseEntity = writeToAuditlog(request, inputHeaders, errorMessage); // Outputs an info log as it supposed to

            return responseEntity; // Outputs the ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver message after the return
        }
        // Do something else in case of another error
    }
}
```

It looks like the logger cannot handle the exception, but why doesn't it tell me why, in case that is true, and why is the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` doing it instead?

**Update:**

I looked into `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` as [saver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67977912/7925759) suggested, and found out that the log comes from `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`'s `logException()`. My custom logger class' method gets called before `logException()`, but it still doesn't print anything. Can it be because it is a `ConstraintViolationException` that contains the field `constraintViolations` and that the logger does not know how to handle this?

There is a `setWarnLogCategory` method that I guess I can switch off if I don't want the Spring log. I just can't find out how. The javadocs for `logException` in `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` indicate that there is a property for this, but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

The issue is in method `subAppend(E event)` in `OutputStreamAppender` that class is parent of `ConsoleAppender` and in line of encoding:
`byte[] byteArray = this.encoder.encode(event);`
Encoder tried serialize `ConstraintViolationException` exception and jackson fails with error: `HV000116: getParameterIndex() may only be invoked for nodes of type ElementKind.PARAMETER.`

[image]

**And as result of encoding is empty byte array in case of exception and this is reason why nothing is logged in console. See below:**

[image]

I don't have a quick fix for that right now.

### Old proposal:

I recommend to debug method `doResolveHandlerMethodException` in `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` class and you can see there is only one place when spring boot logger can log message with warning level and that logger will work only in case when something happened during invoking handler method for exception (For example: incorrect type of parameter in handler method and so on). You will see the reason why your handler method wasn't called.
[image]

Please pay attention to case when class `ConstraintViolationException` can be located in two different packages:

- javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
- org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

of course in our case we should use `ConstraintViolationException` from `javax.validation` package

Comment: The thing is that my handler method is called, which calls the logging method. Yet it doesn't log anything. No exception is thrown and the `invokeAndHandle()` is called.

Comment: @Kikkomann could you create the small project on which I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I finally managed to find the time to make a [reproducible example](https://github.com/Kikkomann/ConstraintViolationExceptionExample). I unintentionally managed to avoid the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` message from Spring, but my [error message](https://github.com/Kikkomann/ConstraintViolationExceptionExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/exception/RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java#L53) is still not printed.

Comment: Cool! I will take a look into example and return with the results

Comment: @Kikkomann please see the update in the answer

Comment: Thanks for helping me to find the problem! What is the procedure when there is a good explanation, but my problem is not fixed?

Comment: I will try to find fix for that issue

Answer (score 0):

Those exceptions are handled in one of the base methods of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. You need to override it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I looked into it and `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` seemed like something I could use, but nothing happens. All the `handleXException` eventually call `handleException`, so I tried to override that one, but it still does not get called.